# Wann insert the source(hive) data into target through scala here source column is less than target column

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive

I want to insert the source(hive) table data into target(hive) table but here column is less in source. How to insert the appropriate column values from source other column values going to be "NULL"

I have tried to get the source column and target column and get the difference(extra_columns).

var sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)

```
var df1 = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM btr_Dev_landing.test_cfmr") 


var src_col = df1.columns


var df2 = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM btr_dev_landing.tra_detail_Report")

var tgt_col = df2.columns

var diff = src_col.toSet - tgt_col.toSet
var extra_col = diff.toList
```

I wanna form "insert into table target_table (col1,col2,...,coln) values(sourceVal1,"null"(not in targetTable),..,sourceValn);"